# Hidden states and layers in LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

From information I read online, hidden states in LSTM are generated from the inputs/time steps, for example, see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjnTl.png.

However, number of hidden states seem to be num_units in Tensorflow, and from various examples I read online, num_units may be very different from the number of time steps in an input. (For example, there can be 500 num_units for a 28 time steps of rows for a 28*28 MNIST image input.)

How does the hidden states/num_units work there?

Also, I also see examples with different numbers of hidden states in different LSTM layers connected together? How are the LSTM layers connected in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

- `num_units`, or the size of hidden state, is not relevant to the number of time steps. The hidden state, which is a vector of size `num_units`, is updated at each time step. So in the diagram in your link, if we look at the first layer (layer 0), then `h1(0)` is a vector of length `num_units`, and so is  `h1(0)`, `h2(0)` ...
- Between different layers, the `num_units` does not need to be the same. The `input_size` of a higher layer need to be equal to the `num_units` of the immediate lower layer, because the hidden state of the lower layer is fed to the high layer as input. For details of how the input vector is connected to the hidden state vector, please google *LSTM cell* and you'll find some good explanations.